# Capitalize the first letter of each word in a filename with powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, uppercase, lowercase, title-case

I want to change the names of some files automatically.

With this code I change the lowercase letters to uppercase:

> get-childitem *.mp3 | foreach { if ($*.Name -cne $*.Name.ToUpper()) {
>   ren $*.FullName $*.Name.ToUpper() } }

But I only want the first letter of each word to be uppercase.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use [`ToTitleCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase) Method:

```
$TextInfo = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
$TextInfo.ToTitleCase("one two three")
```

outputs

> One Two Three

```
$TextInfo = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
get-childitem *.mp3 | foreach { $NewName = $TextInfo.ToTitleCase($_); ren $_.FullName $NewName }
```

Comment: Thanks, the link is for c#, I wonder why there is no doc on Powershell about the Get-culture Object.

Comment: Sadly, it also changes "oneTwoThree" into "Onetwothree".  Boo!

Answer (score 13):

My answer is very similar, but I wanted to provide a one-line solution.  This also forces the text to lowercase before forcing title case.  (otherwise, only the first letter is effected)

```
$text = 'one TWO thrEE'
( Get-Culture ).TextInfo.ToTitleCase( $text.ToLower() )
```

Output:

> One Two Three

Comment: If anyone knows how to do this by instantiating an enum method, PLEASE let me know.  ie:  [TextInfo]::ToTitleCase($text)

Comment: You don't have to lowerise. I tried in PS v5.1 and it converts "rEStarT" to "Restart" without `ToLower` call.

Comment: ToTitleCase() is a little weird to say the least. Yes, your example works but "RIVENDELL" doesn't get converted to "Rivendell"

Answer (score 4):

Yup, it's built into Get-Culture.

```
gci *.mp3|%{
    $NewName = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($_.Name)
    $NewFullName = join-path $_.directory -child $NewName
    $_.MoveTo($NewFullName)
}
```

Yeah, it could be shortened to one line, but it gets really long and is harder to read.

Answer (score 2):

There you go

```
[cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-US").TextInfo.ToTitleCase("what is my name?")
```

Comment: thanks a ton!  also recommend modifying the text with .ToLower() like "whAT IS my NAME?".ToLower(), or else it will not convert to Title Case if all letters in the word are capitalized.